# Loading a dynamic C shared library using JNI which also loads another shared library

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

Using JNI on Java eclipse (Linux), I am loading a dynamic shared library called **first.so**.
So far all goes well.
The problems being, that **first.so** also loads a dynamic library called **second.so**.

When running the program I am getting many "undefined symbol" errors regarding symbols located in **second.so**.

It seems that a library loaded using JNI cannot load other C libraries on run-time because we are in a Java environment. Is my assumption correct?
Do I need special compile flags to compile the **first.so** library or is it special arguments to tell eclipse that it will be trying to load an .so during runtime?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `second.so` another JNI library or just an ordinary C library used only by `first.so`?  If it's a JNI library, I think you might need to load that from Java with `System.loadLibrary()` instead of from C with `dlopen()`, although I don't know for sure.

Comment: second.so is an ordinary C library only used by first.so.

Comment: When building `first.so`, link `libsecond.so` in it.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that a library loaded using JNI cannot load other C libraries on run-time because we are in a Java environment. Is my assumption correct?

No.

How is `libsecond.so` used by `libfirst.so`?  Is it a linked dependency, or is it loaded by `dlopen`?

I've found that something like:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("second");
    System.loadLibrary("first");
}
```

in the class that uses the JNI usually works.

EDIT:  Now that I know how you are loading `libsecond.so` this worked for me:

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        test();
    }

    private native static void test();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("first");
    }
}
```

**first.c** -- The sole translation unit of `libfirst.so`

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Test.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>
#define LIBNAME "libsecond.so"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Test
 * Method:    test
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_Test_test(JNIEnv *env , jclass cls)
{
  void* h;
  void (*sym)(void);

  h = dlopen(LIBNAME, RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL);
  if (h) {
    printf("dlopen " LIBNAME " worked\n");
    sym = (void (*)(void))dlsym(h,"second");
    sym();
  } else {
    printf("dlopen " LIBNAME " failed\n");
  }
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**second.c** -- The sole translation unit of `libsecond.so`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
second(void)
{
  printf("hello from second\n");
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CFLAGS=-fPIC

all : libfirst.so libsecond.so 

libsecond.so : second.o
        $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,libsecond.so.0 -o $@ $^ -lc

libfirst.so : first.o
        $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,libfirst.so.0 -o $@ $^ -ldl -lc

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.so
```

`Test.h` can be produced by `javah Test`.  Note that `libfirst.so` and `libsecond.so` are not linked together.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. libsecond.so is loaded by dlopen.

Comment: Seems to be quite enough just to load libraries in correct order, as shown at the top of the response (`System.loadLibrary("second"); System.loadLibrary("first");`)

Answer (score 0):

All usual rules apply to `dopen()` from a library loaded from Java. Particularly, you check your [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ld_library_path-and-dlopen-422816/), [rpath, runpath](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2004-06/msg00120.html), etc. See also [dlopen failed：cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851184/dlopen-failedcannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)